# What exactly is the last piece of code doing?

Tags: java

```
protected boolean[] bitArray = new boolean[8];

protected void readNextByte() throws IOException {

    latestReadByte = reader.read();
    int decimtalTal = latestReadByte

    for(int n= 0; n < 8; n++){
        int pos = (int)Math.pow(2, n);

        bitArray[7-n] = (decimalTal & pos) == pos;  // THIS LINE

        // what is the bitwise And in bracket == pos supposed to mean?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on the right-hand side of the `bitArray[7-n] =` assignment is testing whether bit `n` of decimalTal is set.  It evaluates to true if the bit is set (nonzero), false if the bit is clear (zero).

Answer (score 0):

@VGR is correct, but to point out a small subtlety when you run into similar code in the future:

`(decimalTal & pos) == pos`   tests if *all* the bits in pos are also set in decimalTal

`(decimalTal & pos) != 0`     test if *any* of the bits in pos are also set in decimalTal

In this example, pos only has 1 bit set because it is a power of 2 so it doesn't matter.